# Using two different modules with the same name in elm

Tags: elm, openapi-generator-cli

I use [openapi-generator-cli](https://openapi-generator.tech/) to generate the elm code for REST apis that are described using [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/resources/open-api/).

Basically that worked well for me so far. But now I have to problem, that I want to access two microservices that are described in individual OpenAPI documents. The problem is, that openapi-generator generates an `Api` and `Api.Data` module for every REST API it generates interfaces for. I already checked the templates in openapi-generator, but these module names are fixed and cannot be changed.

So I wonder: is it possible somehow to use two packages in an elm project, that contain modules with the same names? Any other idea how I can use two separate APIs in one elm project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to rename the modules of one of the generated projects. I would recommend automating this renaming.

[This project](https://github.com/pd-andy/elm-package-prefixer) solves a similar problem, so perhaps it can be useful inspiration.

It might be easiest to just fork the generator and add an option for a module prefix (and potentially contribute it back, as it seems like a generally useful option; elm-graphql already has this).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am post-processing the modules for now on the CI server that generates the modules. Maybe I'll extend openapi-generator at a later point and submit a patch to the project.

Answer (score 3):

If I don't misunderstand you, you could try:

```
import Foo.Api as FooApi
import Bar.Api as BarApi
```

Comment: No, that's not my problem. My problem is, that actually every generated Api client is in a module named the same, i.e. “Api”, there is no prefix to that.

Comment: @Mathias Wimmer If you don't write the modules themselves, just try `sed` I guess.

Comment: I actually patched openapi-generator already to support specifying different module names for different modules.

Answer (score 2):

No. Module names in Elm need to be distinct. You cannot have two modules with the same name in the same project. You will get the following error:

```
Detected problems in 1 module.
-- AMBIGUOUS IMPORT ----------------------------------------------- src/Main.elm

You are trying to import a `Foo` module:

3| import Foo
          ^^^
But I found multiple files in your "source-directories" with that name:

    src/Foo.elm
    src2/Foo.elm

Change the module names to be distinct!
```

Comment: I guess I have to extend openapi-generator or post-process the generated files then. Thank you for confirming, that I don't have to search longer of a different solution.